# IE9 fieldset rounded corners

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I cannot seem to make IE9 render a fieldset with rounded corners whereas other browsers do.
Has anyone encountered this too ?

Comment: Repeat:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635851/support-for-border-radius-in-ie

Comment: @digitalFresh: have you read the question? it's about IE9 - and IE9 supports border-radius (as montioned in your link)

Comment: @digitalFresh: What does that have to do with this?

Comment: Huh, the rounded corners don't show up on Opera 11 either.

Comment: You should report IE9 bugs at http://connect.microsoft.com/ie

Comment: Sadly, yet unsurprisingly, nearly eight years later this is still an issue with IE11.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rounded corners on a fieldset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940191/rounded-corners-on-a-fieldset)

Answer (score 23):

This happens only if you use `<fieldset>` with `<legend>` - without it the corners render ok.

You can fix this bug by applying `display:inline` or `display:inline-block` to your `<legend>` element - but than you have to reposition it back in place by setting `position:relative` and moving it around.

Depending how the styling of your legend looks like (with background it will look the same - without the background the border of fieldset will still be visible behind the letters) you can make it look pretty much the same as in other normal browsers.

Comment: I found that while this did solve the issue in IE, it broke it in chrome. The positioning i had to apply to the legend to move it into the correct place moved it way to far in chrome, was fine in FF and IE though. As a work around i stuck the styles to fix it in IE in an IE only [IE only stylesheet](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/). For the record, the style i used was: `display: inline-block; position relative; height: 30px; top: -15px;`

Comment: Obviously. This goes to an IE only stylesheet - the question is tagged as internet-explorer - this is a fix for IE - you always want to apply the fix to the buggy browser only.

Comment: Check this SO answer for an alternative solution floating `<legend>` http://stackoverflow.com/a/17406564/132599

Answer (score 3):

From my experence in the latest version of IE9, I can not get a fieldset with legend to have a radius.  I have not had any trouble with other borders in IE9, the css3 border-radius works just fine, just fieldset/ledgend.  I'm still scratching my head over this.

Comment: This seems to be a bug in IE9 release for fieldset + legend, which is irritating to say the least.

Answer (score 3):

I too used to use fieldset and for more than just forms, but the constant hit and miss on compatibility has caused me to dump them. Better to write your own CSS DIV Classes that emulate fieldset. Using CSS you can get an exact replica of what fieldset looks like and you have a lot more flexibility and compatibility

Answer (score 1):

its only working in latest rc build , aint working in beta version of IE9
try

```
.class {
 border-radius-right-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Comment: It is a good point to re-iterate -- IE9 is not a released product. It's in beta. Don't expect everything to work. And don't use it as your primary browser if you're not prepared for things to break unexpectedly.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following meta tag:

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It is still problem under **IE11** when using ***legend***
, and the solution is in this thread:

[Rounded corners on a fieldset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940191/rounded-corners-on-a-fieldset/17406564#17406564)

```
 fieldset {
        margin:20px;
        padding:0 10px 10px;
        border:1px solid #666;
        border-radius:8px;
        box-shadow:0 0 10px #666;
        padding-top:10px;
 }  

legend {
        padding:2px 4px;
        background:#fff; 
    }


    fieldset > legend {
        float:left;
        margin-top:-20px;
    }
    fieldset > legend + * {
        clear:both;
    }
```

http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201302/fieldset_legend_border-radius_and_box-shadow/

Answer (score 0):

Fieldset rendering is always fraught with problems with rendering and particularly with printing. It's hardly surprising that it doesn't work.

The standard workaround is to add another container and style that.

Answer (score 0):

To get IE9 to use rounded corners(CSS 3) you have to add this to the HTML header:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />`

Then use CSS as normal: `border-radius-right-bottom:15px;`

I had the same issue & this fixed it.

Comment: IE9 *should* support `border-radius` by default. If you need to use this, it means you have something in your settings that are making it flip into IE8-compatibility mode. You may want to check the settings. If you do use this technique, then you should be able to get away with just `IE=Edge`; the rest are irrelevant, since no other browser recognises `X-UA-Compatible` anyway, and even if they did, why would you want to force them to a given version number (you're fixing a quirk in IE here, not Firefox).

Answer (score 0):

I had an access only to CSS file, so I could not make any changes in HTML, so I made the hack in CSS for IE.

HTML structure was:

```
<form>
  <fieldset>
      ...form content...
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

The whole CSS for all browers and with IE hack:

```
fieldset {
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 1px #3D3D3D solid;
}
@media screen and (min-width:0\0) {
    form {
        border: 1px #3D3D3D solid;
        border-radius: 20px;
    }
    fieldset {
        border: 0 none;
        margin-top: 1px;
        margin-bottom: 1px;
    }
}
```

Of course, if your site has another html-structure, this will not work. Therefore instead "form" you can apply in css to a parent div of your fieldset.