# border-radius is not working on Internet Explorer 9.

Tags: css

```
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
     </head>
      <fieldset class="fieldset_New_border"> 
      <legend> Specimen Actions</legend>
               My  Table Goes Here ..............
      </fieldset>

      .fieldset_New_border{
            -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
             -moz-border-radius: 25px;
             border-radius:25px;
        }
```

Is there any specific way to get IE9 to show border-radius?
    Its working fine on mozila and on other browser. 
    I cannot seem to get it to work myself.
    Please find below two files. Is there any wrong in that.
    Same Code is working with curved border on other browsers but not working on ie 9.

Comment: this should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584444/ie9-fieldset-rounded-corners

Comment: You have a similar question [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381446/ie9-border-radius

Comment: Does your real page have DOCTYPE, HTML and BODY tags?

Comment: Yes MY Real page contains all three DOCTYPE, HTML and BODY tags

Answer (score 0):

first : add a background or border-color,
second: this should work without "x-ua-compatible", in IE press f12 and have a look at the documentmode and browsermode and have a look on the dozens of questions asking for the same

Comment: Yes, I added border-color  without "x-ua-compatible" and its reflecting in IE 9. but not solve issue of border-radius

Comment: (PressF12) your Document Mode should be set to Internet Explorer 9 Standards, is it ? you have a htmL5 Doctype ?

Comment: Yes Document mode is set Internet Explorer 9 and doctype is <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: if so, i have no idea, border-radius works excellent in my IE9

Comment: If I apply this to div tag then its border-radius is working properly.But when I apply it to fieldset there is problem.

Comment: okay than i would make a div perfectly wrapping the fieldset and you got it

Answer (score 0):

Rounded corners on `fieldset`s will not work in IE v9 and lower versions. Try changing that to `div` and see what happens.