# Fieldset not properly displaying

Tags: html, css, legend, fieldset

I'm trying to use a fieldset but it is not working as exactly i wanted...
The legend is displayed outside fieldset...But I want it covered like normal fieldsets.
My code is,

```html
<fieldset style="border:1px solid #999; border-radius:8px; box-shadow:0 0 8px #999;padding:6px;">
<legend style="text-align: left;margin-top:-15px;">References</legend>
//Some Text...
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>References</legend>
  //text
 </fieldset>
```

Comment: Means ? I ve posted a snipped but it runs fine? Have you posted whole of your code?

Comment: Ya, It works fine in the code snippet.But I'm working on a Yii project and it still doesn't work...Check this (question code), it worked but the fieldset is not complete it looks like a water tub... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20414791/border-radius-in-fieldset-doesnt-work

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is in the `margin-top:-15px;`, specifically in the `-15px` which is making the margin `-15px` larger (in other words `15px`smaller!).

Example(Without `margin-top:-15px;`):

```html
<fieldset style="border:1px solid #999; border-radius:8px; box-shadow:0 0 8px #999;padding:6px;">
<legend style="text-align: left;">References</legend>
//Some Text...
</fieldset>
```